# How to convert blob to image to display it on a JLabel in Java?

Tags: java

I have a table "xy" in my MySQL DB in which I have saved an image (.png). What I need is to load the image, convert from blob to image and display it on a JLabel.

Can anybody help me with converting the image?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks! i think it will help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some Code block, if can help you:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(<Your Query SQL>);  
java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob(column);  
InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();  
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
```

at JLabel, you should use BufferedImage.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this ...

```
    // Fetch BLOB from DB
    Blob blb = stmt.executeQuery(...).getBlob("blobColumn");  

    // Read BLOB into byte-Array
    byte[] imagebytes = blb.getBytes(0, blb.length());

    // convert byte-Array into Buffered Image (Subclass of Image)
    BufferedImage theImage=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imagebytes));
```

**handle Exceptions and close streams in real code !**

Comment: thanks for the help! but i dont understand the line with reading BLOB into byte-Array. Could you post the wholel line? thanks

Comment: added the byte array access ... although i like 'code-panda's suggestion since it looks a bit clearer and if it's a really large image it might be better to code it that way